# Simple text editing program in C++

Tags: c++, text, editing

I got a little bit of trouble creating a program that edits text in C++. Keep in mind that I'm still at the beginning of programing. Here is what I must do:

Some text is placed in text file F. I must write a program-editor, which based on the file F, commands and data from the keyboard creates the file FF. The program-editor must recognize and process the following commands:

AN - insert text after the n-th row;

IN - insert text before the n-th row;

CM,N - substitution of the rows from m-th to n-th;

DM,N - deleting the rows from m-th to n-th;

E - end of editing;

where m and n are the number of rows in the file F.The commands are recorded one on row and are made as a menu.

This is the program. I researched a lot in the web about text editing and there are some text editing programs' source codes, but I guess I'm still in the beginning of programing and I find those source codes really difficult to understand. I'm concerned about few things:

Must I manually put text in the text file F and must I add another option in the menu about adding text;

The other thing is about the commands - how do I find and use the different rows from the text so I can insert, substitute and delete rows;

Well that is all. If you have the time please help me, because I really need to know how this program must be done in a not so complicated way and I think it got some valuable things that I could learn from it. Thanks in advance !

Comment: A tip: Read about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). Also read about the [C++ input/output library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io). That should be enough for a very simple line-based text editor.

Comment: Well, your task can be trivial or not depending on HOW you have to do your task in details. Non graphical text writing can be quite hard to handle.

Comment: Read the file and put it in a vector of string, on string/line, then each row is now a index in the vector, and you just have to modify the vector to edit your "file". At the end, just concatene eveything and write it in the file.

Comment: Do you know how to open the file and load the lines into a vector? If so, do you know how to save it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **pseudo-code**, you ll find every **real** function you ll need in the documpentation.:

You ll need to write parse() yourself, all vec.something and input.something are real vector or string function, under a different name, you ll need to search the documentation.

open, close and writeinfile are io function under different name too (and different parameters), again, see the doc

getuserinput is also a renamed basic io function.

*The reason I write this is to give you an idea of how to do this, it is **not** the solution spoon feeded to you, think of it as the algorithm, if you can do your homework without it, it is far better than using it. Also, learn to search the doc, it is really useful*

```
vector<string> vec
int n, m
string input, output

//Open the file
open(your_file)
//Store every line in a string in the vector
while(input != EOF)
{
    input = getalinefrom(file)
    vec.add(input)
}

//You don t need the file for now, so close it
close(file)

//Create your 'menu', presuming text based, if graphical, well...
do
{
    //Get user choice
    input = getuserinput()

    //Every command is just a letter, so check it to know what to do
    if(input.firstchar == 'A')
    {
        //Parse the input to get n
        n = parse(input)
        //Get the line to add
        input = getuserinput()
        //Add it before n
        vec.addafter(n, input)
    }
    else if (input.firstchar == 'I')
    {
        //Parse the input to get n
        n = parse(input)
        //Get the line to add
        input = getuserinput()
        //Add it before n
        vec.addbefore(n, input)
    }
    else if (input.firstchar == 'C')
    {
        //Well, I don t see what is substitution so I ll let you try
    }
    else if (input.firstchar == 'D')
    {
        //Get n and m
        n = parse(input)
        m = parse(input)
        //Presuming n < m, you ll need to check for error
        while(n < m)
        {
            vec.deleterow(n)
            n = n + 1
        }
    }
//Go out of the loop at E since it s the end of the app
}while(input != "E");
//Concatene every line
n = 0
do
{
    output = output + vec.contentofrow(n)
}while(n < vec.length)
//Open the file again, with correct flag it will erase it content
open(file)
//Write your new content
writeinfile(file, output)
//Close the file
close(file)
return 0;
```